# Structural search interface suspend function call

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, structural-search

I have a custom function for wrapping Service api call

I want to add some warning while some api call forget adding safeApiCall{}

```
suspend fun <T:Any> safeApiCall(
  apiCall: suspend () -> T
) {
  //do something
}

interface Service {
  @Get
  suspend fun getUser() : User
  @Put
  suspend fun updateUser(name:String) : User
}

val service:Service
service.getUser() //warning "should use safeApiCall"
SafeApiCall { service.getUser() } //ok
```

This is my attempt , but not working

```
interface $Interface$ {
    suspend fun $Method$ ($Parameter$ : $ParameterType$): $ReturnType$
}
$Interface$.$MethodCall$
```

Comment: Where do you call this `service.getUser()` in? inside a suspended function or not? Not sure how this is related to Intellij's structural search?

Comment: I call service.getUser() in coroutine scope

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha, this is 100% related, as the OP asks for a working template for a structural search.

Answer (score 4):

That was tricky, but here it is:

[image]

You need to use [script constraints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.3/search-templates.html#script_constraints). The idea is to filter the parent of your whole match. There are many ways to do that, e.g. to distinguish them by their type.

Here is my search:

Template:

```
$Service$.$method$($args$)
```

`$Service$` variable filter:

```
Type = you.package.Service
```

`$args$` (optional, though):

```
Count = [0: +Inf]
```

And the most important part, the whole template script filter:

```
__context__.parent.parent.class.name == "org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNamedFunction"
```

It's dirty, I know. For some reason I was not able to make it work with `instanceof`, but you may tune it.

If you do, you may ask: How do I debug that script?

Here is my advice. Open the IDEA's logs (Help -> Show Log in Explorer). Then use `println()` in the script, it will print it's argument to the `STDOUT`:

[image]

You see, here there were two matches, but the parent of the second one (which os ok as per your request) was of a different type. So, a quick guess and dirty fix here was to compare them. A more cunning way would be to get the name of the wrapping construct and check if it's `safeApiCall` or not. I'll leave that to you as an exercise.

Good luck!

Comment: @МихаилНафталь, indeed. My answer is just a starter. It passes the "tests", the original OPs request. As I've noted, OP could improve it to handle any kind of logic. Don't blame me for being to lazy polishing this query.